# Spark Analysis Reduce (Twitter Sentiment)

Tags: java, twitter, apache-spark, mapreduce, sentiment-analysis

I have a question about apache Spark and Java

I'm making an application that streams data from Twitter (Twitter4J). And I'm also making an app that analyse the data. a txt file with JSON tweets.

**StreamingApp:**
*output tweet.txt:*
example: one line of Json:

```
{"id":674534622903054336,"user":"twitter","tweet":"a tweet from twitter #twitter.","date":"2015-12-09T11:22:41CET"}
```

**AnalyzerApp:**

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("TwitterAnalyzerBigData");
final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> jsonFile = sc.textFile("whateverpath/tweets.txt");
JavaPairRDD<Long, String> tweetsFiltered = jsonFile.mapToPair(new TwitterFilterFunction());
```

tweetsFiltered is a JavaPairRDD: **tweet ID : Long** and **tweet: String**

Now I'm using some map functions to get something like this:

```
(1,a tweet from twitter #twitter.,0.0,0.055555556,negative, TWITTER)
```

**(This is random test data)**

- **1** being the ID
- **a tweet from twitter #twitter**: The tweet
- **0.0** : positive score
- **0.0566** : negative score
- **negative** : category sentiment (positive or negative)
- **TWITTER** : category of tweet (a category based on hashtags)

**The question:** how can I reduce this RDD so I get a result like this:

```
TWITTER, 1, 0
```

- **TWITTER**: the category of the tweet
- **1** : total amount of tweets of TWITTER CATEGORY
- **0** : The amount of positive tweets of TWITTER CATEGORY

After the answer of James I made the reduceByKey in Java.

```
JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, Float, Float>> categoryEntryRDD = categoryResult.map(new Function<Tuple4<Long, String, String, String>, Tuple3<String, Float, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple3<String, Float, Float> call(Tuple4<Long, String, String, String> tuple4) throws Exception {
                if(tuple4._3().equals("positive")){
                    return new Tuple3<String, Float, Float>(tuple4._4(), 1F, 1F);
                } else {
                    return new Tuple3<String, Float, Float>(tuple4._4(), 1F, 0F);
                }

            }
        });


    Tuple3<String, Float, Float> reducedRDD = categoryEntryRDD.reduce(new Function2<Tuple3<String, Float, Float>, Tuple3<String, Float, Float>, Tuple3<String, Float, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple3<String, Float, Float> call(Tuple3<String, Float, Float> tuple31, Tuple3<String, Float, Float> tuple32) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(tuple31.toString());

            return new Tuple3<String, Float, Float>(tuple31._1(), tuple31._2()+tuple32._2(), tuple31._3()+tuple32._3());
        }
    });
```

But the reduce method is not the same as reduceByKey, how can I fix this?

My output:
{TWITTER, 1000, 400}
But I also have a category: FACEBOOK with 1000 tweets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good canonical map-reduce problem:

1. Map the tweet entry to a tuple representing the category and a count of 1
2. Reduce the category tuples to sum up the number for each catetory

i.e. pseudocode:

```
+ map the RDD you have (id, tweet, pos score...
- map to a tuple that looks like (category, 1, 1) if the tweet is positive
- map to a tuple that looks like (category, 1, 0) if the tweet is negative

+ reduceByKey where our key is the category using summation
- we end up with an RDD of tuples in the form you want
```

Here is some scala code to accomplish this--java is analogous

```
val categoryEntryRDD = tweetsFiltered.map( mappedTuple =>
    if mappedTuple._5 == "positive" {
        (mappedTuple._6, 1, 1)
    } else {
        (mappedTyple._6, 1, 0)
    }
}

val reducedRDD = categoryEntryRDD.reduceByKey( x, y => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2) )
```

At this point reducedRDD holds tuples that look like (category, total number of tweets of the category, total positive tweets of the category).

Comment: Thanks, it looks great. But I'm using Java at the moment, and you can't use the method reduceByKey on a JavaRDD, any ideas?

Comment: I think it works, but I have a question , what if I have more categories? now It gives me: {TWITTER, 1000, 400}, but in fact I have also a category FACEBOOK for example, and your solution just count everything? :s

Comment: Yeah, the end result is a RDD that has as it's entries all the unique categories and their aggregated info. The first entry might be {TWITTER, 1000, 400}, and the second entry might be {FACEBOOK, 400, 22} if there is data with a category as Facebook.

Comment: Yeah but JavaPairRDD is the only RDD with the method reduceByKey. a simple JavaRDD does not have the method reduceByKey, only reduce.. but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it! With Java

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Float> categoryPositiveTweets = categoryResult.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple4<Long, String, String, String>, String, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Float> call(Tuple4<Long, String, String, String> tuple4) throws Exception {
            if(tuple4._3().equals("positive")){
                return new Tuple2<String, Float>(tuple4._4(), 1F);

            } else {
                return new Tuple2<String, Float>(tuple4._4(), 0F);
            }
        }
    }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float aFloat, Float aFloat2) throws Exception {
            return aFloat+aFloat2;
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Float> categoryTotalTweets = categoryResult.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple4<Long, String, String, String>, String, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Float> call(Tuple4<Long, String, String, String> tuple4) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<String, Float>(tuple4._4(), 1F);
        }
    }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Float, Float, Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float call(Float aFloat, Float aFloat2) throws Exception {
            return aFloat+aFloat2;
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Float, Float>> joinedCategorizedTweets = categoryTotalTweets.join(categoryPositiveTweets);

    JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, Float, Float>> categorizedScoredTweets = joinedCategorizedTweets.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Float, Float>>, Tuple3<String, Float, Float>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple3<String, Float, Float> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<Float, Float>> tweet) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple3<String, Float, Float>(
                    tweet._1(),
                    tweet._2()._1(),
                    tweet._2()._2());
        }
    });
```

Thanks for help!

result:

(TWITTER, 100, 40)
(FACEBOOK, 80, 20)